# Convert text file containing name,value pairs to an object using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, object, customization, key-value

I have a text file containing different variables in the following format

```
{
  name: 'var1_name'
  value: 'var1_value'
}
{
  name: 'var2_name'
  value: 'var2_value'
}
```

It would be helpful if I could parse it so that each object has a `name: <value>` and a `value: <value>`, so it would look like this:

```ps
name       value
---------  ----------
var1_name  var1_value
var2_name  var2_value
```

---

When I use the `ConvertFrom-String` function:

```ps
$result = Get-Content file.txt | ConvertFrom-String
```

the result I get is a 'broken' table that does *not* arrange everything according to what is within the curly braces:

```ps
P1  P2      P3
--  ------  ------------
    name:   'var1_name'
    value:  'var1_value'
    name:   'var2_name'
    value:  'var2_value'
```

How can I get a *PSObject* that includes both the 'name' and 'value' keys, each with their values?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to rewrite the original data to valid JSON and pass it to `ConvertFrom-Json` - or fix it at the source... where did you obtain the data in the first place?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That's unfortunate. The source is a `*.bicep` configuration file using the `appsettings` resource.

Comment: To convert to valid JSON it looks like just a matter of replacing `}` with `},` and surrounding the whole thing with `[]` to make it a JSON array. Are you saying bicep does not use valid JSON? That's a shame why on earth would they do that